# Python List Comprehension Flow Control

Tags: python, list-comprehension, control-flow

Can anyone help me get a list comprehension to run inside a function, It runs from the REPL. I have tried various indentations and placements inside and outside of the while loop and the code will run without error but the ‘newlist’ object is not defined/created
I’m using this list comprehension to split the input string of collect_places().  and I cannot see why the comprehension doesn’t produce a new list.

INPUT STRING

```
'uk, london'
```

LIST COMPREHENSION

```
newlist = [str.split(',') for str in placeList]
```

THIS IS THE CODE

```
import sys
import re

placeList=[]
visits=[[],[]] # created for later use

def collect_places():

"""this function will collect country city pairs"""

while True:
    placed = input('Enter a country and city separated by a comma: ')

    if placed =="":
        sys.exit()

    p=re.search('.*\,.*', placed)

    try:            
        placeList.append(p.group(0))
    except AttributeError as atr:
        print('Try again')        
    continue

newlist = [str.split(',') for str in placeList]
```

THIS IS THE SCRIPT & ERROR

```
        collect_places()
        Enter a country and city separated by a comma: uk,london
        Enter a country and city separated by a comma: eh
        Try again
        Enter a country and city separated by a comma:

        newlist
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File “<pyshell#343>”, line 1, in
        newlist
        NameError: name ‘newlist’ is not defined
```

THIS IS EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY FROM THE REPL

```
        placeList
        [‘uk,london’]

        newlist = [str.split(’,’) for str in placeList]
        newlist
        [[‘uk’, ‘london’]]
```

Comment: If I use 'finally:'  instead of 'continue' then 'newlist' becomes available to list.append() within the function collect_places(), but it still doesn't seem to exist outside of the function collect_places(). I'm then able to append to the list 'visits'. Disappointingly it seems to add each list item twice???

finally:
            newlist = [str.split(',') for str in placeList]
##            return newlist  # this drops me out of the loop      
        visits[0].append(newlist[0][0])
        visits[1].append(newlist[0][1]

)>>> visits
[['uk', 'uk'], ['london', 'london']]

Comment: I formatted the code you pasted in the question.  Can you double check the updated indentation matches that of your program?

Comment: Yes it matches. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: That `sys.exit()` call is weird to me. If you're using that to terminate the function, how is your python prompt even open afterwards for you to see whether `newlist` is defined? Shouldn't the program have exited completely?

Comment: the sys.exit() is to exit when nothing is entered i.e, placed =''' empty string. So as long as you enter a value you'll either raise an exception or get another chance

Answer (score 0):

I realised newlist was not defined as a global variable.

```
Local variables of functions can’t be accessed from outside when the function call has finished:
```

as for the ‘country, city’ being appended twice, it has to do with how many times I ran the input() method as even when an exception was raised the following code still executed:

try:
        placeList.append(p.group(0))